# TFS build runs with old code after checking in changes

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, tfs-2015

Recently, I have been facing this issue where my TFS(2015 update 3) msbuild runs with old code even after checking in changes and saving changes locally in visual studio 2015 enterprise edition. I use build to run Automated UI test by running my machine as test agent.
I can see an agent workspace other than my workspace(don't know if anything to do with it).

Can anyone guide me to correct this issue, or anyway to move forward without facing this issue again?
[image: Repository settings]

Comment: Did you clean the workspace on your build agent?

Comment: Wouldn't agent workspace be cleaned during build? If not how do i do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below items to narrow down the issue:

- Check the source code via web portal, verify that the new changes are
  really checked in.
- Check the definition setting, try to set "**Clean**" to "**True**" in
  Repository tab.
- Also enable the "**Clean**" option in MSBuild step.
- Try to create a new definition with the same settings, then try it
  again.
- Clean the caches for your TFS Application Tier and agent machine,
  then try it again.
- Reboot the TFS and agent machine

---

**UPDATE:**

Below screenshot for your reference, also make sure you mapped the source correctly. You can also try to delete workspace and entire source folder directly from your agent machine, eg `C:\Agent\_work\2\s` (You can get the info from build log)

[image]

Comment: when I set Clean to true in Repository,I get error in build saying project not found. I stopped doing this as entire file was not getting copied on doing this.I have attached Repository settings. Could you please tell me how to clear TFS and agent cache?

Comment: @shenQA If your build doesn't work after a workspace clean then you probably have incorrect workspace mappings.

Comment: Can you please give a proper guide on how to setup the build from start , as I cannot find any solution around this?

Comment: Setting right folder as cloaking cleared errors in build.Also, should I include myproject.dll file to my project or not compulsory?